# iphone bluetouth discovery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I am developing an iphone application that uses bluetouth.

I need to do 2 things.

1. Enable bluetouth if its disabled.
2. Make the phone discoverable.

Can I do both things using code?

Comment: What is a bluetouth :P ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You cannot access the bluetooth using the SDK. Apple does not allow this because of security issues.

So yes, you can try using Wifi to implement your idea then.

Comment: Can't you pop a dialog to the user and ask him to enable bluetouth?

Comment: You can ask the user to do whatever you want. But if your end result is using bluetooth for your app, I don't see any progress.

Comment: Nope. Why don't you try using the Wifi Bonjour instead /?